# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

Tags: java, jsch

While I upload a file from local disk to a remote server,such exception occured:
`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp.execute(Scp.java:215)`

I am sure that the userid and password is correct.Because I can upload any file after I restart the upload thread without modify configuration.

Is it possible that this exception is caused by bad network between my machine and server?Or any other cause?

Comment: Can you show your code (particully the line 215) ?

Comment: This class is not my own code.It is from ant-jsch.jar

Answer (score 2):

EGit (even latest version 3.3.2) does not work properly with JRE 1.8. Downgrade JRE to 1.7 and this error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the fix at https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/issues/458#issuecomment-564670250

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <offline>true</offline>
                <useNativeGit>true</useNativeGit>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```