# "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail" with working passwords

Tags: java, jsch

While trying to upload the file to our server, i am getting the following exception

```
    com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:464)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:158)
        at FtpService.transferFileToReciever(FtpService.java:80)
        at FtpService.transferFileToReciever(FtpService.java:54)
        at FtpService.transferFileToRecievers(FtpService.java:44)
        at FtpService.transferSingeFile(FtpService.java:241)
        at FtpService.main(FtpService.java:26)
    Auth fail
```

The part of function transferFileToReciever from source file is

```
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.addIdentity("/root/.ssh/id_dsa");
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);

        session.setUserInfo(serverinfo);
        session.connect(); //geting exception here

        boolean ptimestamp = true;
```

The passwords are working, since i can do login using ssh, but using JSCh it doesnt work even provided with key, username and password.
Using id_dsa key with java version "1.6.0_25".
What could be the error?

Found other similar question, but not the answer.

Comment: Are you sure that your java program can find and read the keyfile?

Comment: yes, running the program as super user.

Comment: > id_dsa
Shouldn't that be id_rsa?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Tracing the root cause, i finally found that the public key of type dsa is not added to the authorized keys on remote server. Appending the same worked for me.

The ssh was working with rsa key, causing me to look back in my code.

thanks everyone.

Comment: I would give you a bounty if I could for this answer!

Comment: I think only public key should be added to authorized key and not the private key. Hats off to all up :(

Comment: thanks for the comment on years old question, looking forward for an edit from your side here. please contribute and make stackoverflow better, rather than criticizing. :) @AjayLohani

Answer (score 9):

Try to add auth method explicitly as below, because sometimes it is required:

```
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
```

Answer (score 4):

I have also face the Auth Fail issue, the problem with my code is that I have

```
channelSftp.cd("");
```

It changed it to

```
channelSftp.cd(".");
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 4):

If username/password contains any special characters then inside the camel configuration use RAW for Configuring the values like

- `RAW(se+re?t&23)` where `se+re?t&23` is actual password
- `RAW({abc.ftp.password})` where `{abc.ftp.password}` values comes from a spring property file.

By using RAW, solved my issue.

http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html

Answer (score 3):

Example case, when I get file from remote server and save it in local machine
   package connector;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, SftpException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String username = "XXXXXX";
        String host = "XXXXXX";
        String passwd = "XXXXXX";
        JSch conn = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        session = conn.getSession(username, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(passwd);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();

        ChannelSftp channel = null;
        channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();

        channel.cd("/tmp/qtmp");

        InputStream in = channel.get("testScp");
        String lf = "OBJECT_FILE";
        FileOutputStream tergetFile = new FileOutputStream(lf);

        int c;
        while ( (c= in.read()) != -1 ) {
            tergetFile.write(c);
        } 

        in.close();
        tergetFile.close();

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Found other similar question, but not the answer.

It would have been interesting to know, where you have found this question.

As far as I can remember and according [com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901248/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-auth-cancel?rq=1)
try to add to method `.addIdentity()` a passphrase. You can use `""` in case you generated a keyfile without one.
Another source of error is the fingerprint string. If it doesn't match you will get an authentication failure either (depends from on the target server).

And at last here my working source code - after I could solve the ugly administration tasks:

```
public void connect(String host, int port, 
                    String user, String pwd,
                    String privateKey, String fingerPrint,
                    String passPhrase
                  ) throws JSchException{
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    String absoluteFilePathPrivatekey = "./";
    File tmpFileObject = new File(privateKey);
    if (tmpFileObject.exists() && tmpFileObject.isFile())
    {
      absoluteFilePathPrivatekey = tmpFileObject.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    jsch.addIdentity(absoluteFilePathPrivatekey, passPhrase);
    session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);

    //Password and fingerprint will be given via UserInfo interface.
    UserInfo ui = new UserInfoImpl(pwd, fingerPrint);
    session.setUserInfo(ui);

    session.connect();

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    c = (ChannelSftp) channel;
}
```

Comment: googling the exact exception, the link appears is http://stackoverflow.com/q/16642204

Comment: i will give it a try, and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was using below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.42</version>
</dependency>
```

and getting the same exception of Auth fail, but updated dependency to below version and problem get resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while using the maven plugin `git-commit-id-plugin`. I was able to push to the remote of my local git project, but
the plugin was giving this error when running `mvn compile`. It seems the plugin needs the remote of the current git project specified with the `https` protocol. Instead, what I had was:

```sh
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:johnbet/myprojectname.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:johnbet/myprojectname.git (push)
```

I solved the issue setting the remote url with

```sh
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/johnbet/myprojectname.git
```

such that the previous command returns:

```sh
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/johnbet/myprojectname.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/johnbet/myprojectname.git (push)
```

I discovered this by noticing that the remote my project had originally (I cloned it from another GitHub repo) was using the `https` protocol, while the one I set after was not.

See the official documentation about changing a remote repository's url [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#switching-remote-urls-from-ssh-to-https).

Answer (score 0):

We were using both password + public key and getting this error. Our issue was that our public key uses OpenSSH, which Jsch does not support, thus had to use the forked and improved version of Jsch: https://github.com/mwiede/jsch.