# JSCH Auth Fail trying to FTP a file

Tags: java, jsch

I support a legacy web application, and one function is to use JSCH to SFTP an attachment to another server. Our server ops team recently added a new RSA key to the target server on top of the DSA key that's been there, and now we're receiving the com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail error message. Here's the code:

```
public final static void sftpFileToRemoteDirectory(
        String clientConnect, 
        int clientPort, 
        String clientLogin, 
        String encryptedPassword, 
        String path, 
        String remoteFile, 
        byte[] file) 
throws Exception
{
    JSch jsch = new JSch();         
    Session session = null; 
    
    ByteArrayInputStream baInputStream = null;
    
    try {             
        //using port 24
        
        session = jsch.getSession(clientLogin, clientConnect, clientPort);            
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");       
        
        // Decrypt password string and set password
        String saPwd = new EncryptionHelper().decryptString(encryptedPassword);
        session.setPassword(saPwd);             
        
        session.connect();      
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");             
        channel.connect();             
        
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;    
        sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        
        System.out.println("Changing to FTP remote dir: " +
                path);
        sftpChannel.cd(path); 
        
        //get ByteArrayInputStream for file
        byte b[] = file;
        baInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        
        //Put file on server
        System.out.println("Moving " + remoteFile + " to " + path);
        sftpChannel.put(baInputStream, remoteFile); 
                  
        sftpChannel.exit();             
        
    } finally {
        try {
            baInputStream.close();
            
            if (session != null) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Don't throw exception caused by closing stream
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I found [this post that seemed related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148948/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-auth-fail-with-working-passwords). We double checked and made sure that the target server is in the list of known hosts. This includes just the server name, the FQDN, and the FQDN plus the port number, but no luck. Any changes I can make to the code?

The error message:

> 20:40:37,639 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-20) Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
>
> 20:40:37,639 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-20)  at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:461)
>
> 20:40:37,639 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-20)  at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:154)
>
> 20:40:37,639 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-20)  at com.lmig.requestit.utils.RequestITFileManagementUtils.sftpFileToRemoteDirectory(RequestITFileManagementUtils.java:54)
>
> 20:40:37,639 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-20)  at com.lmig.requestit.modules.desktop.automation.Form2039Automation.automateOutlookPhotoMoveFileToPhoto(Form2039Automation.java:109)
>
> 20:40:37,640 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-20)  ... 27 more

Here are the logs from the JSCH:

> 13:41:10,184 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Connecting to "server" port 24
>
> 13:41:10,188 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Connection established
>
> 13:41:10,190 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-1.07 FlowSsh: WinSSHD 5.20
>
> 13:41:10,190 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.44
>
> 13:41:10,190 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
>
> 13:41:10,231 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: aes256-ctr is not available.
>
> 13:41:10,231 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: aes192-ctr is not available.
>
> 13:41:10,232 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: aes256-cbc is not available.
>
> 13:41:10,232 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: aes192-cbc is not available.
>
> 13:41:10,232 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: arcfour256 is not available.
>
> 13:41:10,232 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>
> 13:41:10,233 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
>
> 13:41:10,235 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>
> 13:41:10,235 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>
> 13:41:10,261 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
>
> 13:41:10,262 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
>
> 13:41:10,285 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
>
> 13:41:10,299 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) WARN: Permanently added 'server' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> 13:41:10,299 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> 13:41:10,299 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>
> 13:41:10,312 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>
> 13:41:10,312 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>
> 13:41:10,314 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
>
> 13:41:10,314 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
>
> 13:41:10,330 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
>
> 13:41:10,330 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
>
> 13:41:10,333 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
>
> 13:41:10,333 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Next authentication method: password
>
> 13:41:13,345 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8009-7) INFO: Disconnecting from "server" port 24

Comment: You are using `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` (what is a security flaw, btw), so no change of server host key can cause you any trouble. Even if it did, you would never get to the authentication phase, so you would not get *"Auth fail"* error. Conclusion: your problem is completely different than what you think. Show us [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848).

Comment: Are you able to connect to that server via sftp or ssh directly?
Have you tried to use any of those keys to connect instead of using password?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to connect to the server using SSH. Would using the keys involve using jsch.addIdentity(privateKey) where the private key is the key on the source server? I'm working on adding the logging to get more detail about Jsch.

Comment: Yes, to use private key you need to use jsch.addIdentity()

Comment: I've added the logs from jsch. If I understand that correctly, it seems to not be using any of the authentication methods, including password. Should I be using the jsch.setUserInfo?

Comment: Show us output of `ssh -v user@host`. Did you check server-side log file? You also urgently need to upgrade JSch library.